# Haldane effect plays more important role in promoting carbon dioxide transport than that of the Bohr's effect in promoting oxygen transport why?

Tags: respiration

This is the actual question
And the correct option is "A"

But I can't figure out why

Haldane effect plays more important role in promoting carbon dioxide transport than that of the Bohr's effect in promoting oxygen transport because

(a) oxyhaemoglobin is a stronger acid which donates hydrogen ion (H) which in turn displace carbon dioxide from blood

(b) carbaminohaemoglobin is a stronger acid which splits into hydrogen ion (H+) and bicarbonate (HCO) (c) carbon dioxide reacts with to form acid

that lowers the pH in tissue (d) carbon dioxide is less soluble in venous blood than in arterial blood.

Comment: Please finish the [Tour] and the help on asking questions, particularly [homework question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). As with all homework questions you need to show your own attempt to solve the problem. It will help the more general biologist if you state what you think the Bohr Effect and the Haldane Effect are, and it will also be a starting point for you to weigh the merits of the different statements. Also please edit the question so that the four alternatives start on a new line.

Comment: I have sympathy for you.  "More important role" is a hard thing to quantify, and the semantics of both honorifics blur out into their inevitable chemical consequences which inevitably overlap.  This one seems better addressed by a process of eliminating the wrong answers than in trying to prove the premise true in an absolute sense.  Nonetheless, (a) *is* clearly true as written and it *does* explain why some CO2 is affected that wasn't even stuck to hemoglobin in the first place.